# Rubygem for Param Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking for a good rubygem for param validation

I want to improve the code dupulication like this.

for example,

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def create
    handle_param_missing_exception  unless params[:p1] && params[:p2] && params[:p2] ...and so on
    handle_unvalid_format_exception unless params[:p1].is_email_format
    handle_unvalid_format_exception unless params[:p2].is_integer_format
    # and other huge validations
  end

  def update
    handle_param_missing_exception  unless params[:p1] && params[:p2] && params[:p2] ...and so on
    handle_unvalid_format_exception unless params[:p1].is_email_format
    handle_unvalid_format_exception unless params[:p2].is_integer_format
    # and other huge validations
  end
end

class ClientsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    handle_param_missing_exception  unless params[:p1] && params[:p2] && params[:p2] ...and so on
    handle_unvalid_format_exception unless params[:p1].is_email_format
    handle_unvalid_format_exception unless params[:p2].is_integer_format
    # and other huge validations
  end

  def update
    handle_param_missing_exception  unless params[:p1] && params[:p2] && params[:p2] ...and so on
    handle_unvalid_format_exception unless params[:p1].is_email_format
    handle_unvalid_format_exception unless params[:p2].is_integer_format
    # and other huge validations
  end
end
```

In my project, ever action has this kind of code. I want to remove all the dupulication.

Is there a good rubygem to handle this?

If not, thinking about making a simple gem for this.

Comment: use strong parameters and validating in controller is a bad idea. Instead, use validations in model, which is easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you check [**ActiveModel::Validations::ClassMethods**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html) ?

Ruby on Rails provides some inbuilt helper methods for validation you do not need to use gem for this.

For any kind of format validation you can use `REGEX` with [**`validates_format_of`**](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_format_of)

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i, :on => :create
    validates_format_of :phone, with: /\A(\d{10}|\(?\d{3}\)?[-. ]\d{3}[-.]\d{4})\z/
end
```

You can check `mail gem` for email validation without regex.

To validates `presence` of attribute you can define as:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, :phone, :email, presence: true
end
```

There are numbers of validation methods available like:

- [uniqueness](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#uniqueness)
- [acceptance](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#acceptance)
- [confirmation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#confirmation)
- [exclusion](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion)
- [format](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#format)
- [length](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length)
- [numericality(only_integer)](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#numericality)
- [presence](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence)

You can also create your own [Custom Validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators)

**FYI:** Validation to use in `model` is better idea then to use in `controller`.